# how can this fix problem connection heroku and mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I have a problem connecting mongodb and heroku.

locally I have no problems with the connection

[Heroku logs --tail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHASB.png)

try with uri of a database that you used in heroku without problems and it also doesn't work.
this is my archive for connection

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const express = require('express');
const mongoose= require('mongoose');

const app = express();

const userRoutes = require('./routes/users');
const reportRoutes = require('./routes/reports');


//mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/panic');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;


mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@panic-database-kpamh.mongodb.net/usuarios?retryWrites=true',{
useCreateIndex: true,
useNewUrlParser: true})
.then(db => console.log("db is connect"))
.catch(err=> console.log(err));

//SETTINGS
app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 3000);

//middlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//routes 
app.use('/users',userRoutes);
app.use('/reports',reportRoutes);



//START SERVER
app.listen(app.get('port'),()=>{
    console.log('Server on port',app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Could you provide code that illustrates how you tried to solve this problem - that way  it is easier for people to provide useful and timely answers.

Comment: basically change the uri of the database for another one i'm sure it serves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the Procfile file several times. change the name that the server raises for index